# How would you determine the transformation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose there exists a linear transformation $T$ where $T: \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^5}$ and $T(\textbf{x}) = \text{A} \textbf{x}$. Given

$$ \text{A} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\\ 2\\ 1 \\3 \end{pmatrix} , 
\quad
\text{A} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \hspace{6pt}1 \\ \hspace{6pt}2\\ \hspace{6pt}2\\ \hspace{6pt}2 \\-1 \end{pmatrix} ,
\quad
\text{A} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3\\ 4\\ 3 \\2 \end{pmatrix} ,
$$

how can we then determine the transformation matrix $\text{A}$? What are some "standard methods" to do it? Isn't this the same as finding the change-of-coordinates matrix when making a change of basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Isn't this the same as finding the change-of-coordinates matrix when
>   making a change of basis?

Totally.

Let $P = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1& 0 \\ 1 &2 & 1 \\ 1 & 3& 1\end{pmatrix}$
It's easy to see that $P\in GL_3(\mathbb R)$.
Your equalities can be rewrite:

$$AP= \begin{pmatrix} 1&1&2 \\ 1&2&3\\ 2&2&4\\ 1&2&3 \\3 &-1&2\end{pmatrix}$$
Finally:
$$ A =  \begin{pmatrix} 1&1&2 \\ 1&2&3\\ 2&2&4\\ 1&2&3 \\3 &-1&2\end{pmatrix} P^{-1}$$

Comment: Oh I see, that's neat. I guess we could have also written $\textbf{A}^T \textbf{P} ^T = \textbf{M}^T$ and then row reduce in order to determine $\textbf{A}$, right?

Comment: Almost, because the transposition inverse the product order: $(AP)^{T} = P^T A^{T}=M^T$ and so $A^{T}=(P^{T})^{-1} M^T$. But I don't really see why you want to transpose, my message gives you a way to directly computes $A$: inverse $P$ then right-multiply it with $M$ .

Comment: Yes of course, one might as well row reduce $\textbf{P}$ instead of complicating it with transposes. One more thing: I am not sure I am entirely convinced that $\textbf{A}$ is the change-of-coordinates matrix. Are the vertical elements of $\textbf{A}$ really coordinates of the columnvectors of $\textbf{P}$ in terms of the other vectors in $\mathbb{R^5}$?

Comment: Let's clarify the things: you have a tranformation $T:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^5$. In your initial post, you give the matrix of $T$ in the basis $(P_1, P_2, P_3)$ (where $P_i$ is the i-th column of my matrix $P$) and the "canonical basis" of $\mathbb R^5$. Your question was to "how to compute the matrix of $T$ in the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^3$ and the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^5$". Here is the matter with change of basis.

Answer (score 2):

Let $v_1=(1,1,1)^T, v_2=(1,2,3)^T$ and $v_3=(0,1,1)^T$ then we verify easily that $B=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^3$. Let $B_c$ the canonical basis and $P$ the change matrix from $B$ to $B_c$. Now if $\textbf{x}$ is a vector of $\Bbb R^3$ such that $X=(x,y,z)^T$ is its coordinates  in $B_c$ then $PX=(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)^T$ is its coordinates in $B$ and then
$$T(\textbf{x})=A(PX)=\alpha A v_1+\beta A v_2+\gamma A v_3$$

Comment: How would we determine $\text{A}$ from that line of reasoning?